# Why is require() returning `{}` in the interactive shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules

In the terminal, I navigate to a directory containing a file `WordManager.js`. From there, I type `node` to get into the interactive shell and type `require("./WordManager.js")`. The result is `{}`. The contents of `WordManager.js` are

```
class WordManager
{
    // ...
}
```

I've found conflicting information online about exactly how I should do the export, but I've tried every possible way and nothing works. I've tried `exports.WordManager = class WordManager { ... }`, I've tried `module.exports.WordManager`, I've tried `export default`...

How do I get the behavior I'm looking for - accessing the WordManager class from the interactive shell?

Comment: `module.exports = WordManager;` is the syntax for commonjs modules (eg. Node.js) using the `require` syntax. You can import using `const WordManager = require("./WordManager");`.

Comment: @bradcush It works! I think I may actually have tried that before, but somehow it worked after restarting the terminal. If you `require` something once, does node not re-read the file if you `require` it again later on?

Comment: > does node not re-read the file if you require it again later on? - Yes, it reads the file only once - https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Node you have to declare the exports of a module.

For example, in your file in order to export `WordManager` you will want to assign it to `module.exports`:

```
class WordManager {
    // ...
}

module.exports = WordManager
```

`require()` will return the value of `module.exports` from the required module. Note that if you want to export multiple values you can do so by attaching them as properties to `module.exports`:

```
class WordManager {
    // ...
}

class SpellChecker {
    // ...
}

module.exports.WordManager = WordManager
module.exports.SpellChecker = SpellChecker
```

This can get a bit wordy when exporting multiple exports, so `module.exports` is aliased as `exports` in module scope, so you can do the following instead:

```
exports.WordManager = WordManager
exports.SpellChecker = SpellChecker
```

A word of warning, `exports` can be overwritten but will not update the value or `module.exports` so the following will not work:

```
// Does not work
exports = WordManager
```

Hope that helps.